# write my logic in servlet programme

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets

I want to create an XML file through *servlet* 
Here is my code

```
        out.println("<html>") out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet contactReq</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        //PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        //System.out.println("Hello you are in get method");
        String fName = request.getParameter("firstName");
        String lName = request.getParameter("lastName");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        int phNo = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("phoneNo"));
        add(fName,lName,email,phNo,response);
        out.println("<h1>Successssssssss :"+fName+"</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");`
```

In `add()` I used this

```
File f = new File("src"+File.separator+"xmlparse");
f.createNewFile();//create the file
out.println("<h2>Root:"+f.getAbsolutePath()+"</h2>");
```

but I didn't get this `root :.....` , my file was not created and if I want to write logic in *servlet*. Is this the proper way?

Comment: What is `f` ? where did you declare it ? You have defined `f1` though !

Comment: What do you mean with "you didn't get this"? What is your expected result? And what did you get instead?

Comment: i have already declared  f in my code

Comment: `f` and `f1` are referring to different objects !!!

Comment: w4rumy : i want to display the given value in the browser

Comment: Idiot: yes, just now edited check it again

Comment: How do you get `out` in the `add()` method ?

Comment: To begin with, read [Servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) and [JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) wiki first and then go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/1037210) asnwer carefully. I'm pretty sure, you will have a good start.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to create an HTML page to be displayed to the browser. I recommend you to forward the request to .jsp file. It will make your life much easier.

```
request.setAttribute("attributeName", someValue); //someValue can be String, int, or any other serializable object.
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("somepage.jsp");  
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid XML, that's poorly formatted HTML.
Java has excellent built in tooling for creating XML and parsing it to a Stream, use those to create the XML and send it to the client. No need to much around with String concatenation, files, and stuff like that.
Something like the following works much more reliable.

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory df = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = df.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = documentBuilder.newDocument();
    Element root = doc.createElement("RootElement");
    doc.appendChild(root);
    Element child = doc.createElement("ChildElement");
    child.setNodeValue("Hello World");
    root.appendChild(child);

    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();

    StreamResult resultStream = new StreamResult(response.getOutputStream());
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), resultStream);
```

assuming the ServletResponse is called "response" in your service method.
That's of course not complete code, you'll need to handle the plumbing yourself.

Comment: Thanks for for respond,I have already done this part in normal way, but i am going to confused about this one, can you please help me how can i create/write xml file using servlet

Comment: @Durgaprasad I just did, this will create xml and send it to the client... I'm not going to write your entire application for you.